# storing a list in json data

Tags: python, json

I wanted to have json file that has main key `tested_versions` that stores list of tools along with its versions

```
{
    "tested_versions": [{
        'version': 1.2,
        'tool': 'superb'
    }]
}
```

but when I try to write using `json.dump(file_obj, json_data)`

I get error saying

```
TypeError: <open file '/home/zchang/log/tested_versions.json', mode 'w' at 0x36a09c0> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You've got the parameters to `dump()` backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to switch the order of the parameters in json.dump()

```
with open('file.json', 'w') as file_obj:
    json.dump(json_data, file_obj)
```